# How to accumulate counts from different searches into one (pie) chart?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have 5 different searches I am doing in Splunk where I am getting the count of how many results from that search query.

I've had a look at this thread here:

https://answers.splunk.com/answers/757081/pie-chart-with-count-from-different-search-criteri.html

but its not quite working for me, I'm not 100% sure if its what I want.

My search queries all look something like this:

index=A variable="foo" message="Created*" | stats count

index=A variable="foo" message="Deleted*" | stats count

I ideally want to assign each query to a keyword - such as created, deleted, etc, then do a pie chart based on the counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should be sufficient.

```
index=A variable="foo" message="Created*" OR message="Deleted*" OR message="<repeat this for any other message types you want>" | stats count by message
```

If you can provide some more examples of the events you are trying to chart, there may be alternate approaches that can work for you.

This version will extract the key part of the message (Created, Deleted. etc...) into a field called `mtype` and you can then perform `stats` on that field.

```
index=A variable="foo" message="Created*" OR message="Deleted*" OR message="<repeat this for any other message types you want>" | rex field=message "(?<mtype>Created|Deleteted|...)" | stats count by mtype
```

Comment: Thanks for that! That works as I want it to. Just the only thing is, is there a way to assign each message to a variable? For example currently it groups by "Created blah blah blah" where I would prefer it just to be 'created' as the thing on the pie chart.

Comment: What I suggest is to use a rex to extract the important part of the message into a variable (or field, as its called in Splunk).

I've updated the answer with a version that uses rex to pull out the message type

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much for your quick and in-depth answers :)

Comment: Just another follow up question - more for my learning, would it be possible to rename them a completely unrelated name? For example, instead of 'Created' or 'Deleted' it could be 'a' or 'b'?

Comment: `eval mtype=case(mtype="Created", "A", mtype="Deleted", "B" ...)` and so on and so forth.